# How do I delete a site in IIS when it has a wildcard SSL certificate?

Tags: .net, iis, ssl, process

We're working on a SaaS solution and would like to automate the creation and deletion of system instances. One step in this process is to delete the IIS site but it has proved to be quite difficult.

The problem is that we use a wildcard SSL certificate for all the sites, and if you try to delete the HTTPS binding for the site in the normal way, it will delete the binding for all the sites. This is because the binding has two components, one of which is shared between all the sites. This is just how IIS works. According to the web, you can solve this by either editing the applicationHost file manually or by using the appcmd.exe console app to delete the site, as it does not use the WMA api that IIS relies on.

The solution I'm trying to get to work is running the command line app from within my administration website, but I've hit a wall. The following code shows what I'm trying to do, but I always get the error code 1168, for ERROR_NOT_FOUND. I'm not sure what that means, but if I run the same command directly in the console it works as expected.

```
internal void DeleteSite(string iisName)
{
    // Impersonation of system admin user
    using (Permission.Elevate())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.Arguments = string.Format(@"delete site ""{0}""", iisName);
        start.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe";
        start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;

        using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
        {
            proc.WaitForExit();

            var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
            if (exitCode > 0)
                throw new Exception("Error code " + exitCode);
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is threefold. Is there a better overall solution (must be fully automated)? If not, what am I doing wrong in the above code? And if all else fails, what can I do to debug error codes from console apps in general?

Comment: Do you stop the Site before deleting it?

Comment: Yes. Since the manual use of appcmd.exe worked as expected, I assume that it must be the way that I invoke it from the host application that is wrong.

Comment: Hey , I know its been a while lol , but how did you get around this?

Comment: Good question - I'm not sure if I ever did.